# A robust search on DBpedia by title

Tags: rdf, sparql, wikipedia, dbpedia, wikipedia-api

I need to write a SPARQL query to get movies from dbpedia.
I have wrote almost all the query but I have this problem:

I have all of these titles, and they have to give me the same wikipedia resource:

- Spider-man
- Spiderman
- Film: Spiderman
- Spiderman 1
- Spiderman: the beginning

Target Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man_(film)

I would want a sparql query that let me find the same Wikipedia resource searching by title

Moreover, is there a way to get also the "relevancy" of each result?

Answer (score 4):

try this, it should return either the original page or any other page that redirects to the main page:

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

SELECT ?s WHERE {
  {
    ?s rdfs:label "Spider-man"@en .

  }
  UNION
  {
    ?altName rdfs:label "Spider-man"@en ;
             dbo:wikiPageRedirects ?s .
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible for you to show the query?

for the text search, if you use the official dbpedia endpoint you can probably use the text search facilities of virtuoso.

see here: http://dbpedia.aksw.org/dbpedia_demo/dbpedia/tutorials/ranked_keyword_search/demo.php